# Is it worth spending the extra money for DDR2 1066?

Tags: memory, ddr2

I'm starting to research all the components for a custom rig I plan on building (for development, I won't be gaming on it) and am at the point where I want to choose memory. The motherboard I chose supports DDR2 1300/1200/1066/800/667 and I'm just curious what the difference is between 800, 1066 etc. I'm assuming it's speed related, but I'm wondering if someone can give me a laymens terms explanation, as well as some advice as to whether it's worth the extra dough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDR3 is the current RAM technology...
so if you choose to DDR2 instead make sure it is as fast as it can be. having slow or just a little memory is not a really good option it makes your computer unnecessarily slow...all data as you probably know are loaded in the memory in order to be executed so having a fast processor but just a little (or slow memory) doesn't make any sense..

Comment: OK, so if I go with DDR3, is it worth spending the extra money then for 1066? Is the difference significant?

Comment: Actually yes it is really important...it would be more important going faster than going for DDR3.But it is also really important to have enough memory(over 2Gb).2G would be ok just for coding..But if you feel like compiling big projects or working on intense applications you should definitely go bigger!

Comment: And just be 100% sure you have a motherboard that supports the RAM you are buying - simple mistake made often :)